# Is there an advantage to using setattr() for functions as apposed to just assigning those values to variables the standard way?

Tags: python, function, attributes

I use a simple pygame ball function as an example but this is just a general question

```
def ball(x, y, radius):
    ball.x = 10
    ball.y = 10
    ball.r = radius
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 255), (x, y), radius)

setattr(ball, 'x', 10)
print(ball.x)
```

Comment: in `setattr` you can use string with name of variable. You can't use string in `ball."x"`. And sometimes it can be useful but normally rather nobody use it in normal code.

Comment: No, don't do it.  There are some very specific things that you *need* `setattr` to do (like if you're in the very unusual situation of having a dynamically generated string representation of an attribute name, which only happens if you're doing Deep Magic), but using it unnecessarily will not make your code better.  If you're passing a string literal as the attribute name you almost certainly do not want to be using `setattr`.

Comment: Agreed, another time you might need it is if you're working with heavily customized classes or descriptors. In general you don't need to use it.